# what does "broadly defined" mean?

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "broadly defined"?

Three **broadly defined** groups are at play in the River Valley

Comment: To me, *broadly* in *broadly defined* has a mixed sense of *generally* and *loosely*.

Answer (score 2):

*Broadly defined* means that the definitions employed are very “broad”—that is, they are drawn to cover as many entities as possible and permit a good deal of fuzziness at the edges.

Note, for instance, that your author defines the three groups as “Jordanian citizens on the east side of the river, Israeli citizens to the west, and Palestinians residing on both banks of the river”, but goes on to say that

> These categories can be muted [*i.e., ‘softened’ or ‘relaxed’—StoneyB*] by the recognition that Palestinians are also citizens of Jordan although they are distinguished in political, social, and economic terms from other Jordanians.

The opposite of a *broad* definition is a *narrow* definition. For instance, a December 2013 news item is headlined *YouTube To Hunt Bigger Advertisers With **Narrowly Defined** Channel Searches*:

> Reports today are surfacing that Google is intent on creating a new style of brand advertising for its media divisions, including YouTube and Google+. It’s an entirely different style of thinking for the company’s marketing department, and as such, they are looking to refocus YouTube’s usability to be much more advertising friendly. This means a heavy diversification of channels into much more defined categories instead of the miasma of oddball videos that the current algorithms recommend or suggest.
>       The idea is to make YouTube look much more like a cable TV-style format with **narrowly defined** search channels for items like football, or cooking, or music.

This contrast of *broad* and *narrow* is not confined to definitions. For instance, the allusion to cable TV in the news story above reminds older readers of the revolution in TV content which cable effected. Old-fashioned broadcast TV offered only a handful of channels in any market, each of which presented very similar content appealing to the *broadest* possible market. Cable TV permitted many new channels to arise, each targeting a much *narrower* market—sports fans, children, housewives, men 18-35 years old, and so forth.

Similarly, phoneticians distinguish between *broad* transcriptions, which represent only the most important sound features, and *narrow* transcriptions, which seek to show even very small details. Wikipedia gives an example:

> ... one particular pronunciation of the English word little may be transcribed using the IPA as /ˈlɪtəl/ or [ˈlɪɾɫ̩]; the **broad**, phonemic transcription, placed between slashes, indicates merely that the word ends with phoneme /l/, but the **narrow**, allophonic transcription, placed between square brackets, indicates that this final /l/ ([ɫ]) is dark (velarized).

Answer (score 1):

Broadly defined means "defined at a high-level, which may be overly simplistic".

From *Understanding Life in the Borderlands: Boundaries in Depth and in Motion*: Three broadly defined groups are at play in the River Valley: Jordanian citizens...Israeli citizens...and Palastinians... [the book goes on to describe some overlapping characteristics].

It's like saying European History can be broadly defined as the Pre-classical Period, the Classical Period, The Dark Ages, The Renaissance, The Industrial Revolution, and the Modern Era.  Furthermore, Western Art and Music can be broadly defined as belonging to each of these periods.

Broad Definitions are often used as a starting point for giving a simplified overview, perhaps with further details and refinements to follow.